# Finding the matrix of an parallel projection in the canonical basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I was going through some exercise in a linear algebra textbook to freshen up but I got stuck on one specific question:

> Determine the matrix that represents, in the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, $f$ the projection on the plane $\pi$ defined by $x+2y+3z=0$ parallel to the line $D$ defined by $\frac{x}{3}=\frac{y}{2}=z$.

Im not entirely sure how to go about that. What I know is that the vectors of $D$ are of the form $v=(3\lambda,2\lambda,\lambda),\; \lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. And also I know I'm looking for $f(e_1),\, f(e_2),\, f(e_3)$ where the $e_i$ are the vectors of the canonical basis. But I'm not sure how to do that, I'd appreciate any tips.

Comment: Start by finding vectors of which you do know the image. That is, 2 independent vectors in the plane, and 1 vector in the direction of the parallel direction. From there we can find the corresponding matrix.

Comment: @KlaasvanAarsen Thank you. I will do that.